# simplyScroll - jQuery issues

Tags: jquery, simplyscroll

I was given a project at work which is using simplyScroll for two layers of background images. You can view the site by going to [newcombspring.stifel-marcin.com](http://newcombspring.stifel-marcin.com).

Anyway, when you click to the top background and drag it the bottom half disappears completely. What could be causing this?

Also, I tried using `autoMode: 'loop'` to get the background to continue but it still stops. Any ideas on what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the parent `div` has a `height` smaller than the background itself.

It looks like your background has a height of 620px but `.scroll` div has a height of 300px.

In your stylesheet.css you can modify

```
.scroll {
height: 300px;
}
```

to

```
.scroll {
height: 620px;
}
```

Comment: I caught that right after I asked the question but it still isn't working.

Comment: I debugged it locally and that fixed it on my end. Somewhere the height of scroll is being set to 300 where it should be 620